# Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration! and Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

Tags: android-studio

no puedo virtualizar mis dispositivos moviles en android studio

intente seguir esta pregunta:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration

lo primero fue ver si el harware accelaration estaba instalado y asi fue [image: ro]

2) fui al  directorio de SDK C:\users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\  y ejecute el archivo nombrado intelhaxm-android.exe

pero me dice que la virtualizacion esta apagada
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego descargue este programa y....
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la virtualizacion aparece como habilitada

si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradeceria, acabo de comprar un nuevo computador con procesador intel y estaba muy emocionado porque pense que iba a ser facil virtualizar

tambien intente desintalar y volver a instalar el emulador accelarator pero dio el mismo resultado

Answer (score 1):

- Entré a la bios, allí tenia la ***INtel Virtualization technology y vt-d*** como `disabled`. La cambie a *enabled*.
- Luego fui al directorio de SDK `C:\users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\ y ejecute el archivo nombrado intelhaxm-android.exe`

Me dejó de salir el error y ya tengo el emulador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: debo eliminar la pregunta?

Comment: hace dos horas no sabia que era una bios por lo que tuve que aprender como entrar y modificar la virtualizacion creo que aunque yo mismo respondi, la pregunta le puede ser de utilidad a alguien, el mayor problema estuvo en que yo no entre a la bios de primeras porque no sabia el proceso y encontre el programa ***utilidad intel para identificacion de procesadores***, el cual me decia que tenia la virtualizacion activada lo cual resulto ser falso.

Comment: Si, estoy de acuerdo contigo. No hay que borrar la pregunta. Esto que te paso a ti le puede pasar (y seguro le pasara) a algún otro colega.